# Firewalled port 22 by mistake

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was working on a instance on my account (a drupal bitnami image) and put installed a firewall to block port 80, then forgot to open port 22 before I logged out. Is there anyway Google or I can break back in, I'm assuming no? 3 days work :(

Comment: If you already have a (GCE) firewall rule to allow traffic on port 22, per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh), but you have blocked the port from inside the OS (e.g IPtables), try interacting with the [serial port console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console). If you did not setup a user name and password, you may have to attach a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to create one, and then reboot. Otherwise, check the above troubleshooting document.

Comment: Useful document (for next time!)

Comment: if you already resolved the issue, would you post an answer with the solution for the benefit of the community?

Comment: Didn't solve it, trashed the server and started again :( , serial console has to be enabled before hand. I could have saved the instance and mounted it on another, but in the end I decided that would probably take as long as starting again, luckily I was only at the beginning of a project and not in production

Comment: In the future, if you face a similar issue, you can enable interactive access on the serial console for an existing (running) instance by simply adding a metadata from the UI, or using this command gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]  --metadata=serial-port-enable=1 Further info at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enabling_interactive_access_on_the_serial_console)